# CPU running at 60°C on Yoga 13 – How to control fan speed?

Tags: fan, cpu-load, cpufreq, fancontrol

I am running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 13 laptop. My fan is constantly running. If have tried to solve the problem with TLP , but to no avail. I have also installed cpufrequtils.

On windows the fan is reasonable, ie not running if the computer is doing nothing, and turns on only under heavy load.

I believe the behavious is not due to a bug in the linux software for my fan. With xsensors I see that my cpu's are fairly hot: about 60 deg. Thus it makes sense that the fan turns on to cool down the computer. If I check my cpu's I see that they are constantly running at high speed, so I think the problem is there.

If the computer is not running any heavy software the cpu's should not be running so heavily. I have been trying to use TLP and cpufrequtils to manually scale down my cpu speeds, but this somehow just gets ignored'.

Here is my cpufreq-info output. It shows that I scaled down the processors to maximum 1 Ghz, and also turn on powersave. However it says the processors keep running in 1.80 GHz. What can I do to turn it down, so that (hopefully) my fan will turn down as well?

```
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 774 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.80 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz, 774 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 774 MHz and 1000 MHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.80 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 1.80 GHz:0,11%, 1.80 GHz:0,00%, 1.70 GHz:0,00%, 1.60 GHz:0,00%, 1.50 GHz:0,00%, 1.40 GHz:0,12%, 1.30 GHz:0,00%, 1.20 GHz:0,00%, 1.10 GHz:0,00%, 1000 MHz:0,00%, 900 MHz:0,00%, 800 MHz:0,00%, 774 MHz:99,77%  (3)
analyzing CPU 1:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 1
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 1
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 774 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.80 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz, 774 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 774 MHz and 1000 MHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.80 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 1.80 GHz:0,11%, 1.80 GHz:0,00%, 1.70 GHz:0,00%, 1.60 GHz:0,00%, 1.50 GHz:0,00%, 1.40 GHz:0,12%, 1.30 GHz:0,00%, 1.20 GHz:0,00%, 1.10 GHz:0,00%, 1000 MHz:0,00%, 900 MHz:0,00%, 800 MHz:0,00%, 774 MHz:99,77%  (3)
analyzing CPU 2:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 2
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 2
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 774 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.80 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz, 774 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 774 MHz and 1000 MHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.80 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 1.80 GHz:0,11%, 1.80 GHz:0,00%, 1.70 GHz:0,00%, 1.60 GHz:0,00%, 1.50 GHz:0,00%, 1.40 GHz:0,12%, 1.30 GHz:0,00%, 1.20 GHz:0,00%, 1.10 GHz:0,00%, 1000 MHz:0,00%, 900 MHz:0,00%, 800 MHz:0,00%, 774 MHz:99,77%  (3)
analyzing CPU 3:
  driver: acpi-cpufreq
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 3
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 3
  maximum transition latency: 10.0 us.
  hardware limits: 774 MHz - 1.80 GHz
  available frequency steps: 1.80 GHz, 1.80 GHz, 1.70 GHz, 1.60 GHz, 1.50 GHz, 1.40 GHz, 1.30 GHz, 1.20 GHz, 1.10 GHz, 1000 MHz, 900 MHz, 800 MHz, 774 MHz
  available cpufreq governors: conservative, ondemand, userspace, powersave, performance
  current policy: frequency should be within 774 MHz and 1000 MHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.80 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  cpufreq stats: 1.80 GHz:0,11%, 1.80 GHz:0,00%, 1.70 GHz:0,00%, 1.60 GHz:0,00%, 1.50 GHz:0,00%, 1.40 GHz:0,12%, 1.30 GHz:0,00%, 1.20 GHz:0,00%, 1.10 GHz:0,00%, 1000 MHz:0,00%, 900 MHz:0,00%, 800 MHz:0,00%, 774 MHz:99,77%  (3)
```

Here the output of lspci -v

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at cfa08000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at e0400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at e041c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at e0421000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at e0418000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [130] Root Complex Link
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at e0420000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    I/O ports at 2088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 2094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 2080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 2090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 2060 [size=32]
    Memory at e041f000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 10
    Memory at e041d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at 2040 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family Thermal Management Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3977
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at e041e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
```

Comment: My friend had the same issue. In his case, he did not have any graphic card drivers installed and the load shifted to the CPU. Use `lspci -v` and find the driver for your VGA card.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I added the lspci -v output. As far as I understand I do not really have a graphics card in my computer, it is one of these Intel HD graphics (I will look up precise model)

Comment: What is the output of `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

Comment: Now it says powersave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the computer is not running any heavy software the cpu's should not be running so heavily.

This is a wrong assumption, *one* process running wild on *only one* core may very well utilize all the available **thermal budget** the CPU has to offer and keep the core busy doing nothing.

> Here is my cpufreq-info output. It shows that I scaled down the processors to maximum 1 Ghz, and also turn on powersave. However it says the processors keep running in 1.80 GHz.

Why that? You seem to have a problem with cores being busy for some reason you need to investigate. What problem is this workaround going to solve? **You make your situation worse!** The programs that really have work to do should get it *finished* as quick as possible and go back to sleep before heating up the rest of the system which just means more work for the fan to do to get all the heat back out of this narrow tiny system and you degrade the performance of the device for no good reason. **Powersave governors and under clocking are not your friends!**

Investigate what keeps your cores busy, you may not see all the details in some resource monitoring programs, check their settings or if a reboot  after the device has *significantly cooled* down helps.

There are some useful answers in [fancontrol](/questions/tagged/fancontrol), but again you are likely to make you problem worse, revert every change you made in attempt to troubleshoot, wait for the device to have completely cooled down and focus on **reproducible results**.

---

> With xsensors I see that my cpu's are fairly hot: about 60 deg.

I assume you mean Celsius not Fahrenheit. Depending on the room temperature and the specification of the CPU 60 °C may not be as hot as you think it is or considered "overheating".

Here is example from output from `sensors` on my desktop machine:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +54.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +51.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +53.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +54.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +52.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

[…]

fan1:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:                   798 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:                   835 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:                     0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
```

It considers 80 °C as high and 100 °C as critical. Your Yoga may be different, the thing here is my fans run at low speed at about 28 °C room temperature currently and I can see there is almost nothing going on in *indicator-multiload* (though a Virtualbox VM is running and several applications, webbrowsers and halted videos are open), load or wild processes look different in resource usage.

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly did not think of the possibility of a program hogging the resources. It's hard to trace back what is wrong. But I get the troubles both from Fedora core and Ubuntu. At one point my system log got extremely large and ate all of my root partition ``/'' (the system log file got around 4 Gb big). So probably there is something wrong there